# How to check, if a node() is already allocated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing some groovy helper methods for my Jenkins-pipeline jobs. One of my methods is supposed to be called with and without an allocated node, like this:

```
myMethod() // Call outside of the node (no node allocated yet)
node("...") {
    myMethod() // Call within the node
}
```

Now to implement the method I have to check, if I'm currently inside a node, and if not, allocate one, like this

```
def myMethod() {
    if ( -->isNodeAllocated()<-- ) {
        // Do the stuff
    } else {
        node() {
            // Do the same stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So how to perform this kind of check?

Comment: I remember to have seen a try/catch way in some shared library (maybe fabric8?). First you try to execute without allocating a node, if it fails, you wrap the step in a `node`.

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins sets a environment variable called NODE_NAME if you are in a node.  Try this:

```
if (env.NODE_NAME) {
    // Do stuff 
} else {
    node ('yournode') {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also working in multi-job case using `parallel`? Isn't `env` variable some kind global for all blocks executing in `parallel`?